# Add a button to change background

Tags: jquery, css, fancybox-2

I have gallery with Fancybox v2. I want to make viewing on different backgrounds. On the opened the picture i want to place and three buttons that allow to change external background.
Is it possible to implement it?
Thanks for any and all help and advice.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on the selector that you use. $(body).css({'background-image' : 'url(...your url here)'}) will change the body image. 
so full code:

```
<style>
    body{
        background-image:url(image%20here);
    }
</style>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#button1').click(function(){
            $(body).css({'background-image' : 'url("new%20image%20here")'});
        }
        /*alternative way*/
        $('#button2').click(function(){
            var url = 'new%20url%20one');
            changeBody(url);
        });
        $('#button3').click(function(){
            var url = 'new%20url%20two');
            changeBody(url);
        });
    });
    changeBody(url){
        $(body).css({'background-image' : url});
    }
<script>
</head>
<body>
    <button id="button1">Change 1</button></br>
    <button id="button2">Change 2</button></br>
    <button id="button3">Change 3</button></br>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you. I have a similar code. But i need to use it in Fancybox v2. I forgot to specify it. Does anyone know how to realize this in fancybox?

Comment: Sorry I try not to use plugins. Try looking up on the fancy box size how its done.